# What is the best way to modify a specific field in a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

Specifically what I'd like to do is "alter" one of the fields in the Google Calendar field entry for my own purposes. Namely the location is almost always going to be one of four locations, but the way the Google Calendar is set up it doesn't track frequently entered information, and writing the full address every time (or keeping a notefile w/ the 4 addresses to C&P) is kind of annoying.

Ideal I suppose would be an "extension" or script that would automagically detect that I'm filling out a Google Calendar event entry and change the location field to a drop with the four addresses I frequently use as well as an "other" option.

Another possibility might be some kind of bookmarklet (or set of 4) that fills the location field in.

I don't really know where to start or which method would be better (hell, there might well be a third option that is superior).

PS: If this would be easier/more efficiently done in Firefox or some other browser rather than Chrome that is fine as well.

Comment: Seems like you know what to do, a bookmarklet should do the job. Do you know how to write a bookmarklet?

Comment: No... I'm sure I could find out with a little googling, you think that would be better than trying to write an extension or some other option?

Comment: So I'm moderately convinced the solution is a bookmarklet, but the ID of the where field changes on each event. Would it be better to mark this as "close" and ask a new question or edit this question to more properly reflect where I need help?

Comment: @aslum Updated the solution to be based off the 'textinput' className.  Not guaranteed to be compatible in the future, so you may have to change it if Google updates their site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with bookmarklets.  Here's a potential URL for setting addresses given the current Google Calendar page (the id of the "Where" input is ":1u"):

```
javascript:document.getElementById(':1u').value='123 Some st.'; void(0);
```

I'd write bookmarks with URLs similar to the above for each of your 4 addresses and then put them into an easily accessible folder, and use them each time you want to populate that address.

**UPDATE:**

Since the ID changes, you can get it by the class name.  However, if the class changes or the number of inputs before the Where field changes, you'll have to update your links:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('textinput')[1].value='123 Some st.'; void(0);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Apparently Google doesn't consider the current value of the textbox when a Calendar item is saved.  I fixed this by manually firing the 'change' event after the value of the textbox is updated.  The following currently works in Firefox:

```
javascript:var a=document.getElementsByClassName('textinput')[1];a.value='123 Some st.';var e=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");e.initEvent('change',true,true);a.dispatchEvent(e);void(0);
```

Comment: Weird, for me the id was `:o7`. Any idea why it was different?

Comment: Okay, so the ID changes every time I create a new event. I created a second event and this time the id is `:pp`. Any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: @aslum Interesting.  I have a couple of gmail accounts, and it seems like the id is different for each, but both are consistent across browsers.  I'm guessing Google uses the user accounts to somehow dynamically generate the id's for the page.

Comment: @aslum Oops, just saw your second comment.  This is tougher than I initially thought.  Looks like the main problem is figuring out a reliable way to get a handle on the where input.

Comment: I know it's been nigh on a month (updating the calendar is a once a month job, and I'd basically finished by the time this was answered last month) but google calendar tends to ignore the pasted-in-via-bookmarklet-text ... so when I save the calendar the map field is still blank. Weirdly, the text IS visible in the field. If I edit the field it'll save it (delete the last # of zipcode, and then retype it) or if I Cut and then Paste the whole thing it'll keep it as well. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @aslum - Man, Google does whatever it can to make it not work, don't they? ;)  I found a workaround by firing the 'change' event after the value is set.  See my last update for the example bookmarklet URL.

Comment: You're a genius! Thanks for all your help; I wish I could up-vote your answer more than once... of course, with my luck, next month Google will change something and it'll stop working. /:

Comment: @aslum - Thanks, glad I could help again, and fingers crossed for ya :)